# Determine the frequency of occurrence in XQuery

Tags: function, xpath, xquery, frequency

Is there a way of determining the number of times in which a particular value occurs in a sequence, with XQuery?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for possibly the shortest one-liner solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
count(index-of($value, $sequence))
```

Comment: What I wanted to do this with all the values on the sequence and return the most frequent? 

let $counter := 0, $index1 := 0
for $value in $sequence
if (count(index-of($value, $sequence)))
then {
 $counter := count(index-of($value, $sequence))
 $index1  := index-of($value)
}
else 
{}
...

Comment: This counts as a *new* question. Please, ask it as a question and I'll try to find a good one-liner.