# For loop in dictionary in XQuery

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, xquery, marklogic

I am trying to loop over items and output number of occurrences for each one, but it outputs the same dictionary a number of times equal to the number of items. Is there a way same as using parentheses to just make the loops for  `let`  statements. I know that XQuery is a functional language and that I can use  `group by`  but it is not supported in marklogic.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $dict := map:map()
for $i in ('book1','book2','book2')
let $n := (if (map:contains($dict, $i)) then (map:get($dict, $i)) else (0))
let $dict1 := map:put($dict, $i, 1 + $n)
return $dict
```

Output:

```
<map:map>
<map:entry key="book1">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">1</map:value>
</map:entry>
<map:entry key="book2">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">2</map:value>
</map:entry>
</map:map>
map as 
XML
<map:map>
<map:entry key="book1">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">1</map:value>
</map:entry>
<map:entry key="book2">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">2</map:value>
</map:entry>
</map:map>
map as 
XML
<map:map>
<map:entry key="book1">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">1</map:value>
</map:entry>
<map:entry key="book2">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">2</map:value>
</map:entry>
</map:map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `let` a throwaway variable and then put the for loop FLWOR processing for that variable, then return the `$dict` map:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $dict := map:map()
let $_ :=
  for $i in ('book1','book2','book2')
  let $n := if (map:contains($dict, $i)) then map:get($dict, $i) else 0
  return map:put($dict, $i, 1 + $n)
return $dict
```

Since `map:put()` returns an empty sequence, you could also return a sequence with the for-loop processing and then the `$dict`:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $dict := map:map()
return (
  for $i in ('book1','book2','book2')
  let $n := if (map:contains($dict, $i)) then map:get($dict, $i) else 0
  return map:put($dict, $i, 1 + $n), 
  $dict
)
```

A more concise version of the same processing:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $dict := map:map()
let $_ := ('book1','book2','book2') ! map:put($dict, ., 1 + head((map:get($dict, .), 0)))
return $dict
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @MadsHansen you could also use more functions:

```xquery
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $dict := map:map()
let $myvalues := ('book1','book2','book2')
let $_ :=
  for $i in fn:distinct-values($myvalues)
    return map:put($dict, $i, count(index-of($i, $myvalues)))
return $dict
```

(I picked the "frequency" function with the combination of `count` and `index-of` from [another answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086786/determine-the-frequency-of-occurrence-in-xquery))